# Getting FusionAuthClient is not a constructor error

Tags: fusionauth

I am trying the fusionauth-node-client and following the wiki https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/client-libraries/node. But I am getting the following error

```
const client = new FusionAuthClient('6b87a398-39f2-4692-927b-13188a81a9a3', 'http://localhost:9011');
               ^

TypeError: FusionAuthClient is not a constructor
at Object.<anonymous>
```

I have pasted the exact code mentioned in the doc still it is not working. Can anyone help me in identifying what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug around in the library and noticed that we are exporting several objects and our example is no longer correct.

To get the client you need to change your syntax a little bit to get the correct object.

```
const {FusionAuthClient} = require('fusionauth-node-client');
```

This translates to: require the library `fusionauth-node-client` and give me the `FusionAuthClient` from inside it. There are also a `RESTClient` and `JWTManager` available in the library but you shouldn't need either of those to code with FusionAuth.

I will also update our example to correct this discrepancy.